# ISC-DHCP-Server stopped running / can't clone pool group

Tags: linux, service, dhcp

I'm using ISC DHCP server to manage the ips in my network at home, I am using version 4.4.1-2.2ubuntu6.1. As OS I am running Ubuntu 21.04.

On May 28 it stopped working, the service stopped and in the logs I found "Can't clone pool group". As I haven't changed anything in the config I though at first that an update was the culprit but I wasn't able to find anything. I was unable to start the service again, every time I tried the process exits and shuts down.

So I tried to downgrade and at first it ran with the config I used a longtime, but then quit with the same error: can't clone pool group.

I am at a loss. I don't find anything when I google and the DHCP server just won't run. When I change the config and remove the pool commands, it runs, but that quite seriously misses the point.

So pretty please, have a look at my config and tell me if you see anything out of order. Or maybe even anything you would do in another way.

```
authoritative;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 192.168.1.1;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
        option domain-name "home";
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.30, 192.168.1.1;
        max-lease-time 7200;
        pool {
                range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.199;
                deny unknown-clients;
                max-lease-time 28800;
        }
        pool {
                range 192.168.1.200 192.168.1.249;
                allow unknown-clients;
                max-lease-time 3600;
        }
  host workstation { hardware ethernet AA:AA:AA:AA:AA; fixed-address 192.168.1.60; }
  host .....
  host and some more hosts, all formated the same
}
```

here is the config checked and the response I get.

root@myHomeServer:/etc/dhcp# dhcpd -t -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
can't clone pool group.

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at [www.isc.org](http://www.isc.org) or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging.

exiting.

If you can help. Please do so, this is driving me crazy.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem, too.

It looks like it's a bug in version 4.4.1-2.2ubuntu6.1.

Downgrading to the prior release (20.10) version, 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu10.1 (from groovy-updates), on both primary and secondary, fixed it.

So, for the moment, I've pinned them there.

When I get some time, I may investigate further.